# GNOME disk utility resize is taking forever! Where can I find the progress logs?

Tags: gnome, gnome-disk-utility

This is a 2TB external drive of which 111 GB full.
I am reducing the ext4 partition size to 700 GB.
The resize partition job is running for a couple of hours now.
`/var/log/syslog` has no relevant messages.

Where do I find `gnome-disk-utility` progress logs?

Comment: Looking at progress logs (if any exist) will not help you much, you have to let it finish. That it takes some time is what I'd have expected, there's a lot of data to move (the data will be spread over the whole partition, it's not that the 111GB reside  at the beginning of the partition). It will depend on how your drive is connected to the machine, if you use e. g.  a USB 2.0 port, that will be slooow... Be patient!

Comment: Thanks! "Having patience" worked :) Wish there was more visibility. It'll help people like me with a compulsive behavior to be able to focus on other tasks knowing this is going to take X hours.

Comment: A note to anyone else doing disk ops. Use ```iostat``` to monitor the partition. It provides visibility on the data transfer rate.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but linux developers aren't known for their user friendly interfaces. You're lucky if the app even works half the time and when it does, it'll be missing valuable feedback and polish cause most developers can't be bothered to finish their apps before pushing any old trash online and finding the next shiny thing to make a mess of.